# Escpos commands: feed paper in reverse direction with printer SUNMI V2S PLUS

Tags: escpos, sunmi

I have two machines: 1- **SUNMI V2S** ,2-**SUNMI V2S PLUS**.
And i use escpos command '**ESC K d**' in printer **sunmi v2s** to make paper feed in reverse direction so make paper return back for adjusting,and in SUNMI V2S PLUS it doesn't work even with same commands, and it print directly string like 'Kd'.

```
Dim REVERSEFEEDPAPER As String=Chr(27) & Chr(75)& Chr(100)
Printer1.WriteString(Printer1.REVERSEFEEDPAPER)

Public Sub WriteString(data As String)
'   WriteString2(data, "IBM437")
    WriteString2(data, "UTF8")
End Sub

' Send the string to the printer in the specified encoding
' You also need to set the printer to a  matching encoding using the CodePage property
' Beware of using WriteString2 with Chr() to send numeric values as they may be affected by codepage substitutions
' Most character level operations are pre-defined as UPPERCASE string variables for easy concatenatipon with other string data
Public Sub WriteString2(data As String, encoding As String)
    Try
        If Connected Then
            Astream.Write(data.GetBytes(encoding))
'           Astream.Write(data.GetBytes("UTF8"))
        End If
    Catch
        Log("Printer error : " & LastException.Message)
        AStream_Error
    End Try
End Sub
```

[image]

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance and Best Regards

Azzurra

Comment: Both the [SUNMI V2s](https://developer.sunmi.com/docs/en-US/ceghjk502/fxdeghjk524) and [SUNMI V2s PLUS](https://developer.sunmi.com/docs/en-US/ceghjk502/fxceghjk502) support pages end up on the same page [Inbuilt Non-detachable Printers Documentation](https://developer.sunmi.com/docs/en-US/xeghjk491/ciqeghjk513). The documentation [ESC&POS commands document](https://ota.cdn.sunmi.com/DOC/resource/re_en/ESC-POS%20Command%20set.docx) there doesn't mention an escape sequence for `ESC K d`. Perhaps V2s just happens to have it, and it's an undocumented, unofficial feature.

Comment: I don't know if it's unofficial feature or not, but i wish not, maybe i do something wrong.Because this SUNMI V2SPLUS if i don't feed paper back, the ticket will have a lot of blank space，due to the print head. But Thanks you very very much anyway.